# Java overriding sort function is not working

Tags: java

I have got this overriding in my Java code

```
Arrays.sort(String[] unsorted, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String arg,String arg2){
        if(arg.length<arg2.length){
            return -1;
        }else if(arg.length>arg2.length){
            return 1;
        }else{
            for (int i=0;i<arg.length();i++) {
                if(arg.charAt(I)>arg2.charAt(I)){
                    return 1;
                }else if(arg.charAt(I)<arg2.charAt(I)){
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

But this code gives me plethora of errors like

```
Error: <identifier> expected
    Arrays.sort(String[] unsorted, new Comparator<String>(){
```

Comment: Remove `String[]`. You're not declaring the method, you're calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the place of `String[] unsorted`, you need to put the name of the array you want to sort.